# Use a sub-subject (here/reference) in a scrlttr2 letter?

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, letters, scrlttr2

Of course you can use `\setkomavar{subject}` to add a subject to a letter you have created with `scrlttr2`.
However, many letters from official agencies or other public institutions do have another subject line. It goes like this:

> **Subject: Your request regarding XY**
> Here: Our answer that declines this request

This is especially true for official letters, official orders or so, e.g. regarding FOI requests.

[Here](https://fragdenstaat.de/anfrage/hygieneplanmanahmenplanepidemienplan-corona-pandemie/546422/anhang/03020302_00002_0013_0004_geschwaerzt.pdf) is an real-life example in German:
[image: Betreff: Auskunft nach dem IFG […]; second line: Bezug: Mail von Frag den Staat vom […]]

The first line is the actual subject, the second one describes the content that is actually referred to in this letter, e.g. in a longer conversation.
So you usually keep the subject the same, but change the “reference” or however it may be called to indicate

I've searched the doc for `scrlttr2` as best as I could, but could not find anthing regarding that feature. We can set everything, from date to (numerical) reference of the agency (“Your reference“ as `yourref`, `yourmail` etc.), but I want another subject line that is *optionally* less-bold than the original subject or so.
IMHO this is quite common.

How can I best do this?

Here is an example document that shows the two lines in the subject, at least:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}
\parskip3mm
\parindent0mm % if you want to have no lineskip

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Jerry Garcia\\710 Ashbury St\\San Francisco\\CA 94117}

\setkomavar{subject}{%
    Subject: Your request regarding XY\\
    Here: Our answer that declines this request
}

\opening{Bonjour elliot,}

\lipsum

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

It would be best if the first and second line could be styled totally separate to each other, e.g. first line bold and second line not-bold or vice-versa.

Comment: Does it need to have a label (such as 'Here:'), or is it sufficient to have a two-line subject where the second line is not bold? Could you provide an example document with a letter where you want such a subject, to serve as an easy starting point for potential answers?

Comment: Yeah a label almost certainly is required. I'll make an example.

Answer (score 0):

A pretty simple solution would be to just make a line-break in the `subject` field, but then I cannot style it properly, at least not easily:

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{scrletter}
\parskip3mm
\parindent0mm % if you want to have no lineskip

\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Jerry Garcia\\710 Ashbury St\\San Francisco\\CA 94117}

\setkomavar{subject}{%
    Subject: Your request regarding XY\\
    Here: Our answer that declines this request
}

\opening{Bonjour elliot,}

\lipsum

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```